# Math symbol taking up too much vertical space

Tags: line-spacing

I am using the symbol `$\partial_p^{(K,L)}$` in inline mode in several place in my master's thesis and it takes up too much vertical space---so much that the spacing between the line containing the symbol and the line above it is larger than the spacing between "normal" lines.

How can I solve this?

I realize that one option is to use `\smash{\partial_p^{(K,L)}}` but then the symbol overlaps with a symbol from the line on the top. (Using `\smash[b]{...}` again screws up the vertical spacing.)

Comment: You seem to be between a rock and a hard place.  Something has to give... either a generally larger line-spacing is needed, or you need to retain the `\smash` and artificially introduce some extra verbiage to horizontally offset (thus avoiding) the potential overlap.

Comment: You could try  smaller font (e.g. \scriptsize or \scriptstyle).

Comment: I made several sentences more awkward (e.g. changed "because" into "which follows from the fact that") and now it looks less terrible. I'm definitely not changing the spacing of the whole document because of few sentences.

Comment: You should consider `\partial_p^{\scriptscriptstyle(K,L)}` defining a macro, of course: `\newcommand{\foo}[2]{\partial_{#1}^{\scriptscriptstyle#2}}` and then use `\foo{p}{(K,L)}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply the `\smash` operation only to the subscript term:

```
$\partial_{\smash{p}}^{(K,L)}$
```

Comment: I can say that it does not work (see overlap and larger line spacing): `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
blah blah blah
$\partial_{\smash{p}}^{(K,L)}$
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
blah blah bl
$\partial_p^{(K,L)}$
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
blah blah bl
\end{document}`

Comment: Alright, I should have qualified my recommendation by noting that it *might* result in the superscript of one `\partial_{\smash{p}}^{(K,L)}` term becoming entangled with the subscript of another `\partial_{\smash{p}}^{(K,L)}` term *if* the terms just happen to line up "just right" -- as they do in your sample code. Let's see if the OP weighs in with more information as to whether or not this is going to be a real problem.

Comment: Fair enough.  As you see in my comment, I also recommend taking evasive action to avoid potential overlap.

Comment: Well, this did help (I also reworded the problematic sentences to avoid overlap). Thanks, you guys are great. :-)

Comment: `\smash[t]{p}` would be better (requires `amsmath`).

Comment: @egreg thanks, I'll try. How is `\smash[t]{...}` different?

Comment: @blazs It just removes the height of the symbol, not the depth.